# What are some normal ways of configuring my iOS app to connect to my test environment?

Tags: ios

On OSX I can configure my app to connect to my test environment with a configuration file setting, a command line argument or an environment variable.

What are some conventional ways of doing this for an iOS app?

1. I can modify the Wifi settings in my iPhone to use the IP address of my test environment as an HTTP proxy.
2. I can compile a variant of the app that has the test environment connection details.

Comment: What do you mean as 'test environment'? You need to send requests to testing server, or that?

Comment: What is the problem? You can use config file or command line argument or environment variable. There isn't much difference to OS X app.

Comment: @AndreySapunov By test environment I mean the test server as opposed to the production server.

Comment: @BryanChen I start an iOS app by tapping an icon. Since I don't start the app from the command line how do I set an environment variable or pass a command line argument? If I used a configuration file how would I get the configuration file onto the device/simulator and edit it?

Comment: You do them in the build time instead of runtime.